# Adding Armour to Rig

Tags: modeling, rigging, vertex-groups, parent, inverse-kinematics

So I have a model of the Master Chief (Halo 5) that I downloaded from the internet, and I constructed a rig for him. The rig works fine [image: Rig in action]

But when I add the armour to the rig I get bad distortion (blender treats it like it is clothing, and I guess that's because of the way that I parented the armour to the rig) [image: armour distorting when moving the IK for the arm]

You can see that the body armour has heavy distortion on it, and I don't know how to stop this from happening... I tried to increase the weight of the armour but there are so many vertex groups

Is there any quick way to copy weight paint to all of these groups? Any help on how to make the armour act more like armour would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I couldn't add a third image of the vertex groups so here's a link to the image: http://i64.tinypic.com/345xv5v.png

Comment: Could you provide your .blend file using blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to be able to help you?

Comment: Still wouldn't let me add a third link to the question :( (rep needs to be 10>) so here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3331/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend editing the vertex groups in edit mode for the armor, that way the vertices are all yes and no they way this can be done is by going into edit mode for the armor, removing them all from the groups by pressing control a and then selecting remove for group, and then selecting assign for the groups that correspond to each piece of armor. It might be a bit tedious but it should work. If you don't understand just say so and ill post some screen shots. If you already tried this sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Worked perfectly! And I now have a fully functioning rig, that moves the armour and body correctly. Cheers :)